# Class 1 and 2 medical device recalls

Tags: openfda

How can I structure a question on the FDA OpenApp that will return all Class 1 and 2 medical device recalls for radiation therapy devices over a certain period (e.g. the month of June 2014)?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is as follows ([here is a clickable link though](https://api.fda.gov/device/enforcement.json?search=radiation%20AND%20classification:(%22Class%20I%22%20OR%20%22Class%20II%22)%20AND%20recall_initiation_date:[2012-06-01%20TO%202012-06-30]&limit=100)) which searches for recalls *initiated* during June *2012*, that were classified as Class I or Class II, and had the word "radiation" somewhere in the recall documentation.

`https://api.fda.gov/device/enforcement.json?search=radiation+AND+classification:("Class+I"+OR+"Class+II")+AND+recall_initiation_date:[2012-06-01+TO+2012-06-30]&limit=100`

**There are a number of caveats to keep in mind though:**

- This query relies on "radiation" being included in one or more of the fields listed at https://open.fda.gov/device/enforcement/reference/ such as `product_description` but there is absolutely no guarantee radiation drugs will mention that keyword.
- This query also relies on `recall_initiation_date` be present which appears to only be there for 59% of all the device enforcement reports available in the API ([4639](https://api.fda.gov/device/enforcement.json?search=_exists_:recall_initiation_date&count=product_type) of the [7855](https://api.fda.gov/device/enforcement.json?count=product_type)). Note that field `report_date` seems to have 100% coverage. Maybe the `recall_initiation_date` field is only available after a certain date? More digging needs to be done to make that call.